# How can I reference two databases using Entity Framework database first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx, database-first

I have an MVC project with references to two seperate projects, each of which contains an edmx. Each of the two EDMX projects point to a different database. The two databases have tables with identical names - contacts for instance. I need both, sometimes in the same controller.

I've set up two different contexts, but I get the error "contact is an ambiguous reference between model1.contact and model2.contact.

How can I use two data contexts that have identical entity names?

Comment: How does your model namespace looks like?

Comment: The namespaces are just the name of the projects...

Comment: try to use fully qualified namespace and see what happens. if you hate too long namespace assign an alias for namespace

Comment: do you mean whenever I reference the entities in code? I would have to do that throughout my project...I hope there's another way.

Comment: If you have resharper then you might be able to do it faster :) But before that try full namespace in one place and see it that solves some of the error

Comment: Actually, for this particular project, I only have to do it in 2 controllers, so maybe not that big of a deal. This appears to be a good solution. Put it in a real answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use fully qualified namespace and see what happens. if you hate too long namespace assign an alias for namespace